# How to remove message when opening terminal/solve?

Tags: shell, fedora, package-management

I am receiving the below message whenever I open the terminal.

```
Repository u'ffmulticonverter_stable': Error parsing config: 
Error parsing "baseurl = u'ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable'": 
URL must be http, ftp, file or https not "ppa"`
```

I am currently running Fedora 21. Is there a way to stop this message from displaying every time I open terminal/also how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, I think the command you wish to find is "yum-config-manager --disable ".
In your case, try both "yum-config-manager --disable ffmulticonverter_stable" or "yum-config-manager --disable ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable". What's more is, why are you trying to install a ppa on a Fedora system? It won't work, as ppa is for Debian based systems. If that doesn't work, please attach the output of the command "ls /etc/yum.repos.d/".